# Design pattern for transformation of array data in Python script

Tags: python, algorithm, functional-programming, time-series

I currently have a Python class with many methods each of which performs a transformation of time series data (primarily arrays). Each method must be called in a specific order, since the inputs of each function specifically rely on the outputs of the previous. Hence my code structure looks like the following:

```
class Algorithm:

  def __init__(self, data1, data2):
    self.data1 = data1
    self.data2 = data2

  def perform_transformation1(self):
    ...perform action on self.data1

  def perform_transformation2(self):
    ...perform action on self.data1

etc..
```

At the bottom of the script, I instantiate the class and then proceed to call each method on the instance, procedurally. Using object orientated programming in this case seems wrong to me.

My aims are to re-write my script in a way such that the inputs of each method are not dependent on the outputs of the preceding method, hence giving me the ability to decide whether or not to perform certain methods.

What design pattern should I be using for this purpose, and does this move more towards functional programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Algorithm:
    @staticmethod
    def perform_transformation_a(data):
        return 350 * data

    @staticmethod
    def perform_transformation_b(data):
        return 400 * data


def perform_transformations(data):
    transformations = (Algorithm.perform_transformation_a,
                       Algorithm.perform_transformation_b)

    for transformation in transformations:
        data = transformation(data)
    return data
```

You could have the `Algorithm` class just be a collection of pure functions. And then have the client code (`perform_transformations` here) be the logic of ordering which transformations to apply. This way the `Algorithm` class is only responsible for algorithms and client worries about ordering the functions.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define your methods like this:

```
def perform_transformation(self, data=None):
   if data is None:
       perform action on self.data
   else:
       perform action on data
```

This way, you have the ability to call them at any time you want.

Comment: Specifics aside, I'm looking for higher level guidance on how to structure my overall code